# get the first from a list using slots

Tags: list-manipulation, map, slot

Problem. I work with a list and want to get the first element. For specific reasons I want to use # in combination with Map

For example

```
 data = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {1, 3, 5}};
```

the desired output is {1, 1, 1}

a simple way to do is using First like

`First[data]`

But I want to use # in combination of /@

When I use

```
#[[1]] & /@ lijst
```

the output is

```
{1, 2, 1, 3, 1}
```

The desired output is

```
{1, 1, 1}
```

Who has a suggestion

Comment: try `#[[1]] &@data`  or `# & @@ data`?

Comment: if you _**have to**_ use `Map`, try `#[[1]] & /@ Transpose[data]`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see much practical utility associated with it. I could, of course, be wrong.

Comment: This question makes little sense indeed. On one hand you would like to apply a function to each element (Map), on the other hand, you only like data from the first element; seems contradictory.

Comment: It makes sense if you use a RotationTransform on a list and you need the first element as part of a transformation.

Comment: Then this seems to be an XY Problem ? Maybe try to either rewrite the question so it is really showing what you want to do (what your real problem is).